# Excel: I want copy a subset of the text from cell A2 to cell B2. More specifically, the text to the right of the 3rd decimal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example: Cell `A2` contains abc.123.xyz.foo.com and I want to copy just xyz.foo.com to cell `B2`. I've tried `=RIGHT(A3,SEARCH(".*.*.*",A3))` which returns "om".

I've also tried `=RIGHT(A3,SEARCH("",A3)+[number])` with a variety of values for [number] which does return the expected text but this is too limiting as the # of characters varies and I need all text up to 3rd decimal.

`=RIGHT(A3,SEARCH("",A3)+11)` returns xyz.foo.com but this doesn't satisfy variation in domain names (contents of column A) I expected ".*.*.*" to return all text up to 3rd decimal but, alas, no.

I've searched this site and several others trying to find this use case but haven't found an answer. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: You say third decimal but I see you want everything right of the second, which is it?

Comment: One clarification: Asterisks don't display properly in the posted example. There are asterisks between the decimals - I promise :-).

Comment: Reading the cell from right to left. Working with domain names which start from the right and move left so my use case is needing to capture the first subdomain above foo.com.

Comment: another example: Cell A2 contains ed.ward.jones.junior.foo.com I want to copy junior.foo.com to cell B2

Comment: further example: Column A contains domain names. A2 = 1.2.3.4.5.com  A3 = xx.yy.zz.foo.com  A4 = 11.22.33.44.55.hello.com  I need to copy A2 to B2 as 4.5.com  A3 to B3 as zz.foo.com  A4 to B4 as 55.hello.com

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))-2))+1,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: That works and I would not have come up with that solution on my own. Thanks very much!

Comment: If you end up using this then please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another similar formula.

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","~~",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))-2)),1))
```

[image]